# Can I put UIBarbutton in annotation bar of PSPDFKIT to UIpopover

Tags: ios, objective-c

There is a way to create subclass of PSPDFKIT annotation bar which is subclass of UIToolBar and give the all the UIBarbuttons of toolbar but this buttons could't added to view of popover viewController.give me the idea to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main developer of PSPDFKit here.

The PSPDFAnnotationToolbar is already a subclass of a UIToolbar. You could place it into an UIPopoverController's main UIViewController, but I don't quite understand the purpose.